# Web socket connection failed after deploying in AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I'm working on frontend development using react. Backend is developed using node js.

In our application, we have web socket implemented in it. We are able to establish websocket connection and load server messages whenever it's used locally. (ws://localhost:portNo)

But, the problem is once after the code is deployed in aws,we're not able to establish the web socket connection.

Please suggest some ideas. It would be more helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: We have to know a lot more to tell what the problem could be, could you please explain a little more in depth the overall deployment architecture that you have?

Comment: it sounds like you have a server application running on localhost:portNo on your local machine, but not on the aws machine, connect to your public ip instead, if the serverapp is reachable from public internet

Comment: Let me elaborate my problem, from backend a websocket connection is established using some port no say, 5000.From frontend connection is established using const ws=new WebSocket(ws://localhost:5000)and we are able to get server messages. Now, problem is we're deploying our application to aws, after deploying, if we try connecting ws://localhost:5000, it won't work. I have tried even connecting as ws://server_ip:5000. Hope my question is clear now.